# CL9 dual channel vs CL11 quad channel

Tags: memory, latency

I have to upgrade the RAM of an old PC, for the same price I can buy two kits: four 4GB CL11 modules or two 8GB CL9 modules, both at 1600MHz.  which of the two options gives the best performance?
The motherboard is a MS-7906.

Comment: Does the PC support quad channel? Unless it's server-grade hardware, it won't.

Comment: the motherboard is a MS-7906. It should support double dual channel

Comment: Double dual channel is still dual channel. This platform doesn't support quad channel.

Comment: it doesn't matter that's not the request.  i just asked which of the 2 configurations is better.

Comment: That's not the question in your title.